# Input element text prediction

Tags: html, forms, user-interface

Many sites show suggestions for what you are typing as a drop down, with some showing the most likely result as a "preview" to the right of the cursor in a lighter-gradient font.

For example (this is from Spotlight on my Mac):

[image: spotlight example]

spotlight text suggestion

Is there any way to reproduce this within a standard HTML input element, or does it require a more complicated rich text (e.g. [Slate](https://slatejs.org)) approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible via the `input` tag.

However, there are a couple of ways to do that.

Slate is a option but I think you can craft something way easier.

For example, you can make a `<div>` with the attribute `contenteditable`. When you type, the div expands and after the "input div" you put another element which has the autocompleted results.

Either way you definitely need JS to accomplish that. Wor splicing the String or for going through your possible results. If you still have this problem, I could write a smapp codepen demo.